# Linux Shell script what dirname and ? means?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Can any body tell me what this command means?

```
selfDir=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd) ?
```

I know

- `$0` = running script name
- `pwd` = current working dir
- `cd` = to change dir

What I need is what is **dirname**? and what **?** means at end to make this line completely understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dirname command removes the trailing / component from the NAME and prints the remaining portion. If the NAME does not contain / component then it prints '.' (means current directory)

**Dirname Command Example:**

Remove the file name from absolute path.

Let say my directory path is /usr/local/bin/add.sh. Now i want to remove /add.sh and display only /usr/local/bin, then we can use the dirname command.

```
dirname /usr/local/bin/add.sh
/usr/local/bin
```

**NAME**

`dirname` - strip non-directory suffix from file name

**SYNOPSIS**

```
dirname NAME 
dirname OPTION
```

**DESCRIPTION**

Print NAME with its trailing /component removed; if NAME contains no /’s, output ‘.’ (meaning the current directory).

**Edit:**
Also, Some characters have special functions in linux commands `?` <-- Matches one character

[Source](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_dirname.htm)

Comment: I have almost accepted the answer as it is clear with example but i think you forgot to tell what is "?" at the end in fact what "; pwd) ?" will do

Comment: @Elvin In linux commands, question mark (?) and asterisk (*) are used as so called wild card characters. They can be used to define arguments that match many files or directories

Comment: The question mark seems a bit odd, though. Unless there is a one-character executable in the current directory, it will produce a "command not found" error. If there is, it also seems odd to have a command that executes whatever it matches, rather than an explicit command name.

Comment: @chepner: I think the question mark is an interloper. However, if it really is part of the line, then the assignment creates an environment variable `selfDir` with a value as described in the main command, and then runs a command from a directory on $PATH with the same name as the first single-character file name in the current directory, with the other single-character file names as arguments (and if there is no such file name, looks for a command `?` somewhere on PATH, and fails to execute if there is no such command — there probably won't be). Afterwards, `selfDir` is unset (or unchanged).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: if just ignore the ? then what ;pwd) means? i know pwd means what but here what it is doing excatly

Comment: Ignoring the question mark, then to a moderate approximation, on some systems (Linux-ish), you might get the name of the directory that contains the script assigned to the variable `selfDir`. That depends on `$0` being provided with a full path name, which some Linux variants (or maybe Bash variants) provide, but 'twas not classically done.  If you don't get a full pathname to the script in `$0`, you end up with the name of the current directory in `selfDir` instead. The `cd ...; pwd` combination also has implications when CDPATH is set.  All good clean fun, really.